# Image not rendering on webpage in django website

Tags: html, django

So I am building a website with Django, and on the homepage I want to render an image that is always the same. Here is what I have tried. The pictures and the html file are in the same directory.

This is the html:

```
<div class="ui segment">
<div class="ui horizontal divider">
View the results
</div>
<img src="3.png" alt="View Results">
</div>
```

And this is a picture of my folder:

[image: Folder structure]

The image isn't showing up at all, I just get that small icon that you get when the image doesn't load.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The html you added is from home.html? Because usualy when I get this problem there is just a problem with my path to the image.

Comment: Very vague of a question. Is the image in the same directory as the webpage itself? Is it the right filename?

Comment: Can you access the image directly if you type the URL in the browser's address bar?

Answer (score 2):

You don't put images in the templates directory. You put them in the static directory and refer to them via the `{% static %}` tag.

See the [tutorial on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial06/).